# PHP warning getimagesize

Tags: php, warnings

I am getting these errors when trying to upload an image to the server

> Warning: getimagesize(../images/image-1Product 320120312100APPLE_IMG_0072.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 107
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(../images/image-1Product 320120312100APPLE_IMG_0072.jpg) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 122
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Home.php on line 128

I know why I am getting the third error because of the 1st and 2nd error, I dont why I am getting warnings for 1 and 2, the folder does exist.

> Line 107 - `$size = getimagesize($source);`
>
> Line 122 - `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);`
>
> Line 128 - `imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image,0,0,$x,$y,$thumb_width,$thumb_width,$width,$height);`

If anyone has got any tips It would be much appreciated.

I changed it over to the full path, but got this error `URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration`

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: is your relative path really correct? try absolut path (sorry for my english)

Comment: Try using an absolute path to the image instead of relative.

Comment: What makes you believe that there are files with these names?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Try to enter the complete url to route to the image meaning include the http://
2. Check your rights on the folders meaning : Right 777

Comment: I get this error when I try with the full path `URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration`

Answer (score 4):

This problem is usually solved by reconfiguring the php.ini

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

To do that, you might need to contact your hosting provider.

If you're using Wordpress or any other CMS, it might accure due to a security plugin that's installed.
Most security plugins change the .htaccess in order to prevent unauthorized access to url's, directories and files.

check your .htaccess and search for

```
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

if you find it, remove it (#RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]) and check if it fixed your problem.

Comment: By removing it I'm getting 500 internal server error :( again putting those values is again showing 500 internal server. what might be the causes? any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the space from your file name. I had a problem like this once, and I believe removing the space fixed it.

Change:

```
image-1Product 320120312100APPLE_IMG_0072.jpg)
```

To:

```
image-1Product320120312100APPLE_IMG_0072.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

your $source variable is point to wrong path ..
if you include a php file in other folder that contains this code , try to use local path like this :

```
$source='images/image-1Product 320120312100APPLE_IMG_0072.jpg';
$size = getimagesize($source);
```

don't use '../' if your images folder is in root that first file is there .

Comment: if the images folder is not in the root, its on the server, but not in the root

Comment: ex:your www folder contains two other folder such as 1-images  2-includes and your index.php . if index.php is include a file in "includes" folder you can not use "../images" to access to images folder on that file.because your first file that will be processed is index.php .maybe it is your wrong . i'm sure that your $source is pointing to wrong path.

Comment: `root/images` & `root/upload` are the folders I want to upload to...the file that is doing the uploading is `root/admin/home.php`

Comment: which file contains $source and in which folder? are you using direct url like:"site.com/admin/home.php"  ?